# Data Scraping with td VBA

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I  am a VBA beginner and I want to scrap a specific data from website using vba. I have seen some questions here but still confused. The data I want to scrap doesn't have id.

It shows:
td align="RIGHT" headers="hdr1 hdr3 hdr12 hdr21"

How could I use vba to extract this data to excel?
The webpage is https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/g17/Current/default.htm
And the data I want is within the first table, first row under the Aug.column,104.4.

Many thanks.

Comment: what version of Excel and do you have Power query? https://www.google.com/search?q=power+query+scrape+data&tbm=vid

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:
`strStatisticsAugust = myHTMLDocument.getElementsByClassName("statistics")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(2).getElementsByTagName("td")(4)`